# How to fetch tokenURI from Polygon smart contract?

Tags: tokens, contract-design, nft, polygon

I am trying to analyse different tokens in terms of the metadata they link to. I found a Polygon-based token project: https://opensea.io/assets/matic/0x50c2eae4903261b386c27c1733588e867f1a33db/10200

I wanted to check what the metadata of this token looks like and here's the problem. After checking on Polygonscan (https://polygonscan.com/address/0x50c2eae4903261b386c27c1733588e867f1a33db#code), the smart contract code needs to be decompiled. However, after decompiling, the tokenURI cannot be found. Somehow OpenSea downloads the image and displays it correctly. How can I then try to manually verify the token metadata and determine e.g. where the graphics are stored? Let's assume we are talking about this token - 10200

Answer (score 0):

The contract returns true when querying for the ERC721 interface ([EIP 165](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-165) "Standard Interface Detection").

Using the standard [EIP-721](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721) you could query the tokenUri for existing events. For example it returns `https://meta.fanadise.com/0x50c2eae4903261b386c27c1733588e867f1a33db/100` for tokenId 100.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to decompile the smart contract to get the *tokenURI*. You can just load the contract instance in Remix IDE with the correct interface.

Here is one way how to do that:

1. Create a new workspace from *OpenZeppelin ERC721* template.
2. Compile the *SampleERC721* contract.
3. At the *deploy & run transactions* tab

   - Make sure you connected to the Polygon Mainnet
   - Select *ERC721* contract
   - Set *At address* to 0x50c2eae4903261b386c27c1733588e867f1a33db
   - Then call the `tokenURI` method with needed `tokenId`.

The tokenURI method will return `https://meta.fanadise.com/0x50c2eae4903261b386c27c1733588e867f1a33db/10200` for the tokenId 10200.